# React App - Cannot redirect to home page after logging in

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a web application using the MERN stack. I have a problem redirecting the user to home page after they login. Here's the idea:

1. User enters login credentials
2. The server validates these credentials and creates a cookie

Problem: The user should be redirected to the home page after this, but the same login page reloads instead.

Here are relevant code snippets:

1. client/App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = backend;
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{setLoggedIn, loggedIn}}>
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>

        <Routes>
          <Route path='/home' Component={Home} />
          <Route path='/register' Component={Register} />
          <Route path='/login' Component={Login} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

2.client/Home.jsx

```
const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {setLoggedIn, loggedIn} = useContext(AppContext);

  const getAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/');
      if(response.data.status === "OK") {
        console.log("Already logged in");
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else {
        console.log("Not logged in");
        setLoggedIn(false);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/logout');
      if(response.data.status === "OK") {
        setLoggedIn(false);
        navigate('/login');
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getAuth();
    console.log("After getAuth()" + loggedIn);
    if(!loggedIn) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='bg-blue-50 h-screen flex items-center'>
      <div className='mx-auto'>
        <h1 className='block mx-auto'>Welcome to the Home Page</h1>
        <button className='block p-3 bg-blue-500 rounded mx-auto mt-3' onClick={logout}> Logout </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

3. client/Login.jsx:

```
const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const login = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await axios.post('/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password
    });

    if(response.data.status === "OK") {
      console.log("Logged in successfully");
      navigate('/home');
    } else {
      alert("Incorrect Password");
      setPassword("");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='bg-blue-50 h-screen flex items-center'>
        <form className='w-64 mx-auto mb-12' onSubmit={login}>
            <input value={username} type='text' placeholder='Username' className='block w-full p-3 mb-3 border' onChange={(event) => {setUsername(event.target.value)}}/>
            <input value={password} type='password' placeholder='Password' className='block w-full p-3 mb-3 border' onChange={(event) => {setPassword(event.target.value)}}/>
            <button className='bg-white w-full text-blue-500 block rounded-md p-3 border-3 border-blue-500'>Login</button>
            <Link to='/register'> <p className='text-center mt-3 text-blue-800'>New here? Register now</p> </Link>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

4. Handler for `GET /` route:

```
const verifyLogin = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const decodedToken = await jwt.verify(req.cookies.token , process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        console.log(decodedToken);
        if(decodedToken.userID) {
            res.json({status: "OK", message: "Cookie is present. Allow access to protected sites"});
        } else {
            res.json({status: "Error", message: "User login cookie not found"});
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        res.json({status: "Error", message: "User login cookie not found"});
    }
}
```

5. Handler for `POST /login` route:

```
const login = async (req,res) => {
    const loginInstance = await UserModel.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(loginInstance) {
        if(loginInstance.password === hash(req.body.password)) {
            try {
                const token = await jwt.sign({userID: loginInstance._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
                res.cookie("token", token).status(201).json({status: "OK", message: "Login credentials are correct. Cookie created"})
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        } else {
            res.json({status: "Error", message: "Incorrect password"});
        }
    } else {
        res.json({status: "Error", message: "User not found"});
    }
}
```

6. Handler for `GET /logout` route:

```
const logout = (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie("token");
    res.json({status: "OK", message: "Cookie has been cleared"});
}
```

Here's how I want it to work like:
On successful login, the user is redirected to home page and after the user logouts, they land at the login page again.

Comment: Does the `console.log("Logged in successfully");` trigger?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes, it does.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? In v6 you should be using `element` instead of `Component` to define the component for the route.

Comment: I'm using v6 version of react-router-dom. I changed ```Component``` to ```element``` in the ```Route```s. It could not solve the issue though

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `loggedIn` state to `true` before navigating to the `/home` page. So when the `Home` component renders, the `useEffect` will make sure you'll be redirected back to the `/login` page.

As you'll see in the **console** the output is `"After getAuth()false"`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getAuth();
  console.log("After getAuth()" + loggedIn);
  if (!loggedIn) {
    navigate("/login");
  }
}, []);
```

So you can set the `loggedIn` state to `true` when you're checking the response of the request.

```js
const login = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const response = await axios.post("/login", {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  });

  if (response.data.status === "OK") {
    console.log("Logged in successfully");
    setLoggedIn(true); // here
    navigate("/home");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect Password");
    setPassword("");
  }
};
```

I would suggest you'd take a look a the [official react-router auth example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/auth/src/App.tsx). This touches the base of protecting routes in your app.

Comment: After a successful login, wouldn't the ```useEffect```  of ```Home``` trigger the ```setLoggedIn(true)``` by calling ```getAuth()```? And wouldnt this ```useEffect``` then not navigate to ```Login``` (The problem is that the ```useEffect``` navigates to ```Login```)?

Comment: It will but the `loggedIn` value is not updated immediately so it will still be `false` when reaching the if statement.

Comment: Thanks! I learned some important stuff about ```setState```s while solving this issue!

Comment: I noticed that the code structure in this application is similar to this one, i.e. the same problem may occur at multiple places in my code because the state is not updated yet. How do I solve this issue if the next step after ```setState``` is  working with the updated state ?